# Is it possible to get dynamic columns on wpf datagrid in mvvm pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm developing a product in wpf (using the MVVM pattern). According to the user's customization (user ll select the columns) I have to display a set of data into a datagrid. Currently I'm binding an `ObservableCollection` with set of properties to the `ItemSource` of the datagrid. This limits me to fixed column size.

Note: The n number of columns name is listed out for user's selection.

If its done in code behind it is easy by "datagrid.columns.add()". Can any one out there help me in this scenario.

my xaml:

```xml
<my:DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Margin="357,121.723,82,41"
    Name="dataGrid3"
    c:DataGridExtension.Columns="{Binding ColumnCollection}"
    />
```

my command class:

```cs
public static class DataGridExtension
{
    public static ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> GetColumns(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)obj.GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetColumns(
        DependencyObject obj, ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Columns",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>),typeof(DataGridExtension),
         new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>(),
            OnDataGridColumnsPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnDataGridColumnsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
           DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d.GetType() == typeof(DataGrid))
        {
            DataGrid myGrid = d as DataGrid;

            var Columns = (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)e.NewValue;

            if (Columns != null)
            {
                myGrid.Columns.Clear();

                if (Columns != null && Columns.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridColumn dataGridColumn in Columns)
                    {
                        myGrid.Columns.Add(dataGridColumn);
                    }
                }

                Columns.CollectionChanged +=
                    (object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
                {
                    if (args.NewItems != null)
                    {
                        //foreach (DataGridColumn column in args.NewItems.Cast<DataGridColumn>())
                        //    myGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                    }

                    if (args.OldItems != null)
                    {
                        //foreach (DataGridColumn column in args.OldItems.Cast<DataGridColumn>())
                        //    myGrid.Columns.Remove(column);
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my property in viewmodel:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> _columnCollection =
    new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();
    
public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> ColumnCollection
{
    get
    {
        return this._columnCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        _columnCollection = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("ColumnCollection");
        //Error
        //base.OnPropertyChanged<ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>>(
        //   () => this.ColumnCollection);
    }
}
```

Comment: mvvm does not restrict you to use codebehind

Comment: Crude way - Create all the columns upfront and hide what is not selected by the user.

Comment: blindmeis, as u said mvvm does not restricting me codebehind, my TL are...

Comment: as i said, im using ObservableCollection<Interface> so the properties(columns) are predefined my friend "Angshuman Agarwal".

Comment: Angshuman Agarwal - the number of columns differs according to the users role, in simple n number of columns. so how can i create a property for that.

Comment: @vinoth then your TL is simply wrong and did not understand mvvm :) but nevertheless one way you can achieve what you want, is with good old DataTable and AutogenerateColumns=true

Comment: Another option is to use an attached property and bind that to some List of "ColumnInfo" objects in your VM and create the columns in code in the PropertyChanged callback of the attached property.

Comment: @blindmeis yes i know either by autogeneratecolumns=true or by datagrid.columns.add() if i need DataGridTemplateColumn, we can solve this scenario through codebehind . Is there any way to achieve this through mvvm itself.

Comment: @HighCore can you suggest me some samples.. pls..

Comment: First google hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065758/wpf-mvvm-datagrid-dynamic-columns

Comment: @HighCore - System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression" is not of type "Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn", since my observable collection is of "ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>" this type.(error from you suggested site)

Comment: @VinothEzhilanM I don't know dude, post your current code and XAML, otherwise I couldn't magically tell you what going on there.

Comment: @HighCore as you asked i have posted my code...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns

Comment: This is the best answer I saw so far :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for your effort guy's... finally i have found the solution....

here its..(full wpf mvvm)

In my command file:

```
public class DataGridColumnsBehavior
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableColumnsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableColumns",
                                                typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>),
                                                typeof(DataGridColumnsBehavior),
                                                new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableColumnsPropertyChanged));
        private static void BindableColumnsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = source as DataGrid;
            ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> columns = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>;
            dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
            if (columns == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            foreach (DataGridColumn column in columns)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
            }
            columns.CollectionChanged += (sender, e2) =>
            {
                NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs ne = e2 as NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs;
                if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
                    if (ne.NewItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                        {
                            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    if (ne.NewItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                        {
                            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Move(ne.OldStartingIndex, ne.NewStartingIndex);
                }
                else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
                {
                    if (ne.OldItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.OldItems)
                        {
                            dataGrid.Columns.Remove(column);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns[ne.NewStartingIndex] = ne.NewItems[0] as DataGridColumn;
                }
            };
        }
        public static void SetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element, ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> value)
        {
            element.SetValue(BindableColumnsProperty, value);
        }
        public static ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> GetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)element.GetValue(BindableColumnsProperty);
        }
    }
```

in my xaml:

```
<my:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="357,121.723,82,41" Name="dataGrid3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Datatable}" c:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding ColumnCollection}" />
```

and finaly in my viewmodel:

```
private ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> _columnCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();
        public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> ColumnCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return this._columnCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                _columnCollection = value;
                base.OnPropertyChanged("ColumnCollection");
                //Error
                //base.OnPropertyChanged<ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>>(() => this.ColumnCollection);
            }
        }
        private DataTable _datatable = new DataTable();
        public DataTable Datatable
        {
            get
            {
                return _datatable;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_datatable != value)
                {
                    _datatable = value;
                }
                base.OnPropertyChanged("Datatable");
            }
        }
```

and in my constructor:

```
public MainViewModel()
        {
Datatable.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
            Datatable.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(string));
            Datatable.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(string));
            Datatable.Rows.Add("Vinoth", "#00FF00", "456345654");
            Datatable.Rows.Add("lkjasdgl", "Blue", "45654");
            Datatable.Rows.Add("Vinoth", "#FF0000", "456456");
System.Windows.Data.Binding bindings = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Name");
            System.Windows.Data.Binding bindings1 = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Phone");
            System.Windows.Data.Binding bindings2 = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Color");
            DataGridTextColumn s = new DataGridTextColumn();
            s.Header = "Name";
            s.Binding = bindings;
            DataGridTextColumn s1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            s1.Header = "Phone";
            s1.Binding = bindings1;
            DataGridTextColumn s2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            s2.Header = "Color";
            s2.Binding = bindings2;

            FrameworkElementFactory textblock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            textblock.Name = "text";
            System.Windows.Data.Binding prodID = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Name");
            System.Windows.Data.Binding color = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Color");
            textblock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, prodID);
            textblock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap);
            //textblock.SetValue(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, color);
            textblock.SetValue(TextBlock.NameProperty, "textblock");
            //FrameworkElementFactory border = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
            //border.SetValue(Border.NameProperty, "border");
            //border.AppendChild(textblock);
            DataTrigger t = new DataTrigger();
            t.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("Name"), Converter = new EnableConverter(), ConverterParameter ="Phone" };
            t.Value = 1;
            t.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.LightGreen, textblock.Name));
            t.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, bindings, textblock.Name));
            DataTrigger t1 = new DataTrigger();
            t1.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("Name"), Converter = new EnableConverter(), ConverterParameter = "Phone" };
            t1.Value = 2;
            t1.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.LightYellow, textblock.Name));
            t1.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, bindings, textblock.Name));

            DataTemplate d = new DataTemplate();
            d.VisualTree = textblock;
            d.Triggers.Add(t);
            d.Triggers.Add(t1);

            DataGridTemplateColumn s3 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            s3.Header = "Name 1";
            s3.CellTemplate = d;
            s3.Width = 140;

            ColumnCollection.Add(s); 
            ColumnCollection.Add(s1);
            ColumnCollection.Add(s2);
            ColumnCollection.Add(s3);
    }
```

Comment: How is this Pure MVVM approach when you are using "DataGridColumn" from System.Windows.Controls in your ViewModel?

Comment: Note - this code is fixed in another Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986380/datagridcolumn-with-header-already-exists-in-the-columns-collection-of-a-dat  . See Jones answer.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to extend the previous example (answer) the ability to subscribe and unsubscribe on event CollectionChanged.

**Behavior** (add reference on System.Windows.Interactivity):

```
 public class ColumnsBindingBehaviour : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> Columns
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>) base.GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Columns",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>), typeof(ColumnsBindingBehaviour),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnDataGridColumnsPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnDataGridColumnsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = source as ColumnsBindingBehaviour;

        var oldItems = e.OldValue as ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>;

        if (oldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var one in oldItems)
                context._datagridColumns.Remove(one);

            oldItems.CollectionChanged -= context.collectionChanged;
        }

        var newItems = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>;

        if (newItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var one in newItems)
                context._datagridColumns.Add(one);

            newItems.CollectionChanged += context.collectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> _datagridColumns;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        this._datagridColumns = AssociatedObject.Columns;
    }


    private void collectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                if (e.NewItems != null)
                    foreach (DataGridColumn one in e.NewItems)
                        _datagridColumns.Add(one);
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                if (e.OldItems != null)
                    foreach (DataGridColumn one in e.OldItems)
                        _datagridColumns.Remove(one);
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                _datagridColumns.Move(e.OldStartingIndex, e.NewStartingIndex);
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                _datagridColumns.Clear();
                if (e.NewItems != null)
                    foreach (DataGridColumn one in e.NewItems)
                        _datagridColumns.Add(one);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="_dataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <loc:ColumnsBindingBehaviour Columns="{Binding DataGridColumns}"/>        
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
     private ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> _dataGridColumns;
     public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> DataGridColumns
     {
         get
         {
             if (_dataGridColumns == null)
                 _dataGridColumns = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>()
                 {
                     new DataGridTextColumn()
                     {
                         Header = "Column1"
                     }
                 };

             return _dataGridColumns;
         }
         set
         {
             _dataGridColumns = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("DataGridColumns");
         }
     }
```